# configuring the oracle procedure so that it should accept the input value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created an procedure which delete the 3 months old partition from the table now i want to make the below procedure configurable enough such that it should accept the count from the user so please advise how can i modify the below procedure

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE Delete_partitions

/*
This procedure will delete partitions for the following tables:
TEMPTABLE
*/

BEGIN
  FOR cc IN
  (
  SELECT partition_name, high_value
  FROM user_tab_partitions
  WHERE table_name = 'TEMPTABLE'
  )

    dbms_output.put_line('starting to drop  partition ');    
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN               
IF sysdate >= ADD_MONTHS(' || cc.high_value || ', 2) THEN                  
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE                     
''ALTER TABLE TEMPTABLE DROP PARTITION ' || cc.partition_name || '                     
'';               
END IF;    
  dbms_output.put_line('drop partition completed');        
END;';
  END LOOP;

  exception
    when others then
        dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);

END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Add some parameters to it:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE Delete_partitions(cnt in number)

/*
This procedure will delete partitions for the following tables:
TEMPTABLE
*/

BEGIN
  FOR cc IN
  (
  SELECT partition_name, high_value
  FROM user_tab_partitions
  WHERE table_name = 'TEMPTABLE'
  )

    dbms_output.put_line('starting to drop  partition ');    
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN               
IF sysdate >= ADD_MONTHS(' || cc.high_value || ', ' || cnt-1 || ') THEN                  
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE                     
''ALTER TABLE TEMPTABLE DROP PARTITION ' || cc.partition_name || '                     
'';               
END IF;    
  dbms_output.put_line('drop partition completed');        
END;';
  END LOOP;

  exception
    when others then
        dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);

END;
/
```

Comment: Well do you think that exception handling is best managed within this procedure or we can add some improvements further there.